# About points on affine curves defined over finite fields

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

So let $\mathbf{F}_q$ be a finite field with $q$ elements where $q=p^m$,

$p$ a prime number and $m\in\mathbf{Z}_{\geq 1}$. Let $f(x,y)\in \mathbf{F}_q[x,y]$

be a smooth non-constant polynomial and let $A:=\mathbf{F}_q[x,y]/(f)$.

Q: Does there exists an integer $N_0$ (which depends on $A$) such that for $N\geq N_0$ one

may always find a prime ideal $P\subseteq A$ such that $A/P\simeq\mathbf{F}_{q^N}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is "yes", given what we know about the number of points on the corresponding projective curve (or more accurately a smooth model of it, in case of singularities). Since points at infinity and singular points can be bounded terms of the degree of *f*, they don't affect the asymptotics here. So the question comes down to the existence of points with a given field of definition, of size a large power of *q*. The calculation that the main term gives the right answer (>0) can be read off the case of the affine line, where it is certainly true.

Comment: Well now that I think it is obvious. If $C$ is the corresponding curve
then we have an exact formula for $\#C(\mathbb{F}_{q^n})$. It is
$q^n+1+(error term)$. Nous using weak Weil estimates we are done.  

Comment: and I should say that for a proper divisor $d|n$ $\#C(\mathbb{F}_{q^d})=q^d+1+(error term)$ so weak estimates imply that $C(\mathbb{F}_{q^n})-\bigcup_{d|n,d\neq n}C(\mathbb{F}_{q^d})$ is
larger than 1.